# Javascript returns false when retrieving an Id value through "container.find()"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

My MVC application contains a simple textarea element (a User profile description) that can be edited by a user that is logged in and represented by a Model in the same view.

A JS function in the view is activated by a "Save" button that takes the textarea value and user id via the Model. These values are sent to the controller which updates the database.

However, I'm unable to discern why my code does not return the Id and String values I need to call back to the controller.

```
var id = container.find('div[data-rel]');
```

returns

```
"false"
```

and

```
var text = descriptionForm.value;
```

returns "undefined"

I'm posting this here as I've spent a great deal of time on this and am unable to see what is wrong with my code. I would highly appreciate a pointer or two!

VIEW:

```
@model MyProj.Models.ApplicationUser

    <div class="row" style="padding: 15px;">
        <div data-rel="@Model.Id"> //The user id

            <textarea rows="10" class="textarea"></textarea>

                //The Save button once editing is complete
                <input type="button" data-input="edit" value="Save" id="saveButton">
            </div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
      $("#saveButton").click(function () {
        var container = $(this).closest('.row');
        var id = container.find('div[data-rel]');
        var descriptionForm = container.find('.textarea');
        var text = descriptionForm.value;

        var url = "/Profile/EditDescription?id=" + id + "&s=" + text;
        $.post(url, null, function (data) {
    });
<script>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
    public void EditDescription(string id, string s)
    {

        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
            new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

        var user = manager.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);

        user.ProfileDescription = s;

        manager.UpdateAsync(user);

    }
```

Comment: `var text = descriptionForm.value;` should be `var text = descriptionForm.val();` as `descriptionForm` is jQuery object.

Comment: How many buttons do you have with an ID of `saveButton`?

Comment: Hiya! Just the one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to get the element you want i.e the `div` with `[data-rel]`, then take the data attribute value using `data()`. For retrieving the textarea value, use `val()` instead of `value`.

```
  $("#saveButton").click(function () {
    var container = $(this).closest('.row').find('div[data-rel]');
    var id= container.data('rel');
    var descriptionForm = container.find('.textarea');
    var text = descriptionForm.val();
    var url = "/Profile/EditDescription?id=" + id + "&s=" + text;
});
```

Comment: Super! Works as it should now. Thank you so much!